# Trajectory of particle from vector velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, vectors

The problem is this: a particle, initially at the origin, has velocity $\mathbf{v}=a\mathbf{i}+bx\mathbf{j}$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Find the trajectory $y(x)$ of the particle.

I went about this two ways, reaching two separate conclusions.

**Method 1**

We have $v_x=a$ and $v_y=b$. Therefore, at time $t$, $x=at$ and $y=bxt$. It follows by elimination that $y=(b/a)x^2$.

**Method 2**

We have $dx=v_x \ dt$ and $dy=v_y \ dt$. The ratio of these is $dy/dx=bx/a$. Integrating, we find that $y=(b/2a)x^2$.

The second is apparently correct. But what is the fault with the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite straightforward though quite frequently made by students. It would have helped if you had explicitly written $x$ as $x(t)$:

$$dy = bx(t)dt$$
Therefore, $$y = b\int x(t)dt $$
You can carry on the computation to check that both methods are consistent.